# Mongo: Find docs where field is a prefix of a string literal without using $where

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all documents where a given field is a prefix of an input value. In SQL it looks like this:

```
... where input_value like concat(field, '%')
```

I want to do this in Mongo 2.4.8 (very much preferably) *without* using `$where`. It's easy with `$where` but I can't use `$where` because I want to use a pipeline so I can use `$project` to derive some fields. And [apparently](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions) you can't use `$where` in pipeline a `$match`. And as far as I can see you can't use the pipeline `$project`-ion operators in a normal [find() projection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) - argh.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be to construct a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) pattern. The below example demonstrates the construction and usage of a regexp. There are alternative ways one could build a regexp.

sample insert scripts:

```
db.t.insert([
{"name":"sampleString"},
{"name":"sam"},
{"name":"s"},
{"name":"sample"}
])
```

sample code:

```
var input = "sample";
var pattern = ''
input.split('').reverse().forEach(function(i,j){pattern = '('+i+pattern+')?'}) // (s(a(m(p(l(e)?)?)?)?)?)?
var regexp = new RegExp("^"+pattern+"$");
```

and use it as:

```
db.t.find({"name":{$regex:regexp}});
```

or:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"name":{$regex:regexp}}}
])
```

That would give you:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cba179d99d86bcb7251107"), "name" : "sam" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cba179d99d86bcb7251108"), "name" : "s" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cba19fd99d86bcb725110c"), "name" : "sample" }
```

> *And as far as I can see you can't use the pipeline $project-ion operators in a normal find() projection - argh.*

You can definitely, use project fields in a `find()` statement as below, though you cannot modify the projected field.

```
db.t.find({"name":{$regex:regexp}},{"fieldToProject":1});
```

Comment: Thanks, The regexp is not quite right but I get the general idea. What I meant about the project operator is that the projection operand to find() does not support deriving new values like $project does. find() only supports classical projection - adding and removing fields from the output (that is my read of the docs, and what I see in testing it out at least).

Comment: Welcome. Right, If you would want to modify and project a field, then aggregation would be the way to go. You could edit to make the pattern better.

Comment: updated regexp. OK, I guess I'll go with this for now. Not exactly straight forward but will do.